# How does one pass a Router into a component as a prop in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have a React component that contains a `<BrowserRouter/>`, but would like to be able to pass in any of `react-router`'s `Router`s as a prop in order to test it easily. I've tried a few ways, but nothing I've tried makes typescript happy.

This first attempt won't work because I can't come up with a type annotation for `Router` in the props that will work. I thought `react-router-dom`s `Router` type would work, but it doesn't.

```
export interface TestProps {
    Router: React.ComponentClass | React.StatelessComponent;
    // also tried: Router, BrowserRouter | MemoryRouter | etc.
}

export class TestComponent extends React.Component<TestProps, any> {
    render() {
        const { Router } = this.props;
        return (
            <Router>
                // ...some routes here
            </Router>
        );
    }   
}
```

I made a stab at passing the router in as a JSX.Element as well, but that won't work either, since the TestComponent would need to set the props.children for that element.

Is the only way around this to make an HOC for each of the Router types?

*EDIT*: While almost certainly not the *right* way to do it, `React.cloneElement()` will let me do what I want to for now.

```
export interface TestProps {
    router: JSX.Element;
}

export class TestComponent extends React.Component<TestProps, any> {
    render() {
        const { router } = this.props;
        const children: React.ReactNode = (
            <div>
                // ...some routes here
            </div>
        );
        const Router = React.cloneElement(router, router.props, children);
        return (
            <div>
                {Router}
            </div>
        );
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) HOC?

Comment: @HardikModha I couldn't find a way to use `withRouter` to pass a Router into a component...just to allow a component access to the router enclosing it. I suppose I could require the top level of the application to wrap the component in a router, but it feels strange to write a component that only works if you remember to wrap it in a router. It seems common in React though. I can't find a good example of using withRouter in typescript, though.

This gist (https://gist.github.com/mikebridge/96a4487aa185343c13bfba5fcc3b431b) might work, but...wow, that's a lot of fussing with types.